Undoing a migration for a duplicate field
We have had a duplicate field added to of our Django Wagtail models which has confused the migration system.
The following was added to one of the models while back along with a migration that added a singular instance of the field:
    stream = fields.StreamField(
        who_funds_you_blocks,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Additional content",
    )
    stream = fields.StreamField(
        who_funds_you_blocks,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Additional content",
    )

The migrations are a bit strange. This is what was committed to the repository
/modules/core/migrations/0014_whofundsyoupage_stream.py
from django.db import migrations
import modules.core.blocks.core
import modules.core.blocks.override
import wagtail.core.blocks
import wagtail.core.fields
import wagtail.images.blocks


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0013_articlepage_apple_news_url'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='whofundsyoupage',
            name='stream',
            field=wagtail.core.fields.StreamField([('rich_text', wagtail.core.blocks.StructBlock([('text', modules.core.blocks.override.RichTextBlock(label='Body text', required=True))], group=' Content')), ('image', wagtail.core.blocks.StructBlock([('image', wagtail.images.blocks.ImageChooserBlock(required=True)), ('alt_text', wagtail.core.blocks.CharBlock(label='Override image alt-text', required=False)), ('caption', wagtail.core.blocks.RichTextBlock(features=['link', 'document-link'], label='Override caption', required=False)), ('credit', wagtail.core.blocks.RichTextBlock(features=['link', 'document-link'], label='Override credit', required=False)), ('image_display', wagtail.core.blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[('full', 'Full'), ('long', 'Long'), ('medium', 'Medium'), ('small-image', 'Small')]))], group=' Content')), ('html_advanced', wagtail.core.blocks.StructBlock([('segment', wagtail.core.blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=modules.core.blocks.core.list_segment_choices, help_text='Only show this content block for users in this segment', label='Personalisation segment', required=False)), ('html', wagtail.core.blocks.RawHTMLBlock(label='HTML code', required=True)), ('styling', wagtail.core.blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[('default', 'Default'), ('remove-styles', 'Remove style')]))], group=' Content'))], blank=True, verbose_name='Additional content'),
        ),
    ]

And although that commit seems to have been integrated, the current migration list doesn't seem to have it, instead the list is like this:
0012_articlepage_apple_news_id_and_more.py
0012_merge_20230531_1543.py
0013_articlepage_apple_news_url.py
0014_merge_20231024_1447.py
0015_alter_articlepage_share_header_and_more.py
0016_whofundsyoupage_stream_and_more.py
0017_delete_targetedlocalehomepage.py
0018_auto_20240226_1608.py

And none of those migrations actually refer to the WhoFundsYouPage model or field.
The only migration in that list whose name refers to that model doesn't appear to include any actual reference to the field:
/modules/core/migrations/0016_whofundsyoupage_stream_and_more.py
# Generated by Django 4.2.8 on 2023-12-13 10:36

from django.db import migrations, models
import wagtail.blocks
import wagtail.fields


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0015_alter_articlepage_share_header_and_more'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articlepage',
            name='apple_news_id',
            field=models.UUIDField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Apple News ID (automatically generated)'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='articlepage',
            name='apple_news_url',
            field=models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Apple News URL (automatically generated)'),
        ),
    ]

Nevertheless, this all seemed to be fine, and the project continued with new fields and migrations being added elsewhere without any problem.
If I comment out the duplicate stream field and try to create a page from that model, I get this error which shows that the database does contain the field:
Exception Value:    

null value in column "stream" of relation "core_whofundsyoupage" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (54264, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, no, no, 1, , , null, null, null).

Recently, the duplicate field was spotted and removed from the models page.
Now, if we try to add a field on some model and a migration for it, the migration is created but doesn't complete, although there are no errors that directly imply it has failed:
(.venv)  development  ➜ app  manpy migrate
/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/utils/widgets.py:10: RemovedInWagtail70Warning: The usage of `WidgetWithScript` hook is deprecated. Use external scripts instead.
  warn(
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'freetag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'pagetag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'sectiontag_chooser' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, core, csp, django_cron, donations, importers, sessions, submissions, taggit, taxonomy, users, wagtail_localize, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailsearchpromotions, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying core.0019_utilitypage_show_navigation_bar_and_more...

The same thing happens if we add the duplicate stream field back and create a new migration i.e. the migration looks like it runs ok but there's no confirmation tick.
And when I start the server we get:
You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migration for app(s): core.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

The database appears to have the field already but the migrations system wants to try to add it again but can't and this is blocking all other migrations.
If I comment out both stream fields, migrations can be made, but the site breaks on the page where the database expects a stream field to be present. I suppose I could delete the stream fields and manually drop the stream field in the database, though we would lose some data by doing that, and I'd prefer to fix this with Django and migrations.
Any idea how to unpick this?

Hmm...curious, can you post your migration files? I'd seriously doubt you have duplicate field names in your DB. Migrations are simply a programmatic way to alter table structures (and maybe data), they can be changed or --faked to ensure they reflect your DB schema. I'd be a little worried that running a new migration to remove a duplicate field in your Model (not DB) would cause the main field to be removed...I'm very interested in your migration files

Thanks @ViaTech I have added more info. Any ideas?

Actually nothing looks too strange to me. I'm very positive other SO members may not like this suggestion, but if your DB structure is accurate, you could (at least in dev first) test my solution to reset your migrations from base. Understand my example before you run it, as it does some serious clean up, but I have found this to be a workable solution both when I want to fix migration issues (as long as the DB schema is right), or remove a ton of dev work with migrations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890759/8382028 I do not see the secondary stream migration run though, maybe it is there?

Thanks again for the suggestion. Our production database is very large and cannot bear much downtime so I think I would probably look for a simpler solution than this. But I appreciate yours is possibly the best solution on the table so far, kudos for that.

understood...however, my option is zero downtime. You have your right DB structure in tact, you just need to make sure you don't have migrations set in the migrations DB table or in your migration files that cause issues. This is where you are not having a DB issue, which can cause downtime, rather a code issue communicating with your DB, which can/maybe could be fixed with a method I had used to reset migrations in the past. All I do in my option is delete migration files locally, delete the entries for the django_migration table, then run fake migrations to fix structure and files.

It's a little difficult to give advice without seeing your migration files and database. It sounds like your database table only has one copy of stream, right? So once you remove the duplication in the model file, the database table and your python model will match.
Assuming that's your situation, then I would edit your old migration files to remove mention of the duplicate. Then try running migrate and makemigrations + migrate on a copy of your production database until you are satisfied that everything works as you want it to.
If your table has duplicate columns, my first question is how could that have happened and my second would be what database are you using? I am fairly sure you can't have duplicate columns in the database but if so, it will be a longer conversation.

Yes, migration files need to be seen to answer here. So once you remove the duplication in the model file, the database table and your python model will match....is only true on the DB schema as duplicate fields names (as far as I know) are not allowed in any DB. If somehow there is a duplicate migration stored in the DB, the solution can be more complex, like deleting the wrong migration from django_migrations table. I do have a solution in Django noting how to reset your migrations from scratch based on current schema here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890759/8382028

@cnk I have added migration files. Any thoughts? Thanks

@KindOfGuy You show the field being added in /modules/core/migrations/0014_whofundsyoupage_stream.py. FInd any file after that that tries to add or alter the stream field. grep stream /modules/core/migrations/*.py. Those are the files you will want to edit. I am going to guess that there is an alter rather than an add.

@cnk strangely, the migration file I show above where the field is added was PR'd but doesn't seem to actually be in the repo. And when I grep stream modules/core/migrations/*.pyI don't actually see a migration that adds stream to that model, which is weird. Any other ideas?
